# Need to download GWT eclipse plugin version 3.5 that google apparentlyy deleted

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

It seems Google took the Eclipse plugin (version 3.5)  for GWT (version 2.4) down because it is too old.  I found a posting to this effect on the Google community site.

I have some old software I have to fix, upgrading any of the software is out of the questions, and no one thought to archive the Eclipse plugin.  This was originally at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5

Can someone please help me locate this?  Thanks!

Comment: Erm, Eclipse is **just** an IDE, you can work without the GPE. Or you can use a newer Eclipse and newer GPE, it shouldn't change your code, and if/as you keep the same GWT version, it shouldn't change your app (I say "shouldn't" rather than "won't", because it depends how you _build_ your app; I know some people —strangely— rely on Eclipse as a build tool, rather than Ant or Maven)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Eclipse galileo? Newer versions may not see it as a valid plugin for that eclipse version.

Comment: Our particular software (JBoss ESB version 4.7) depends on the JBoss developer studio that in turn is based on Eclipse 3.5.  We've tried later Eclipse versions and discovered that we have to keep the JBoss and JBoss developer studio installs in sync.  Later versions are missing build options we depend on and produce mysterious failures.  I have no budget to rework the build and force my company to retest the entire system from scratch. 

The moral of the story: put important stuff under SCM control while you still can!

I'm hoping somebody out there did this.